# How do I run a php script every time it is accessed on a page?

Tags: php, rotator

I am using [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/) image rotator. It's great, but if I link to it multiple times on one page, it displays the same image. I don't know how many times it will be accessed, so using multiple identical scripts is impractical.
How do I modify this script so that I can get a different image elsewhere on the page while using the same url? Is it possible?

EDIT: It turns out that there must have been some problem with the coding. I found a better code [here](http://robm.me.uk/articles/image-rotation-in-php), and it works if I use different queries on each link. Thanks to everyone who submitted answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a different query string for each instance so that the browser retrieves it multiple times.

Your browser is seeing that each "rotated" image uses the same URL, so it caches the resulting image from the first request.

You can change this behaviour in two ways.

1. Suffix your "rotated" image URLs with a random string from php. Eg (**"rotate.php?img=my_static_image.jpg&x=12345"** This means the browser makes a fresh request for each image.
2. Make your rotate scrip [redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to a randomized url if it recives no extra parameters.

Comment: Agreed, but perhaps you can explain why this works? ( caching at client? ) perhaps changing the way the script works will help.

Comment: It works because without it the browser thinks it's all the same image and only loads it once.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new at php. Could you please give a simple description of how to do this? :P *is noobish* Thanks!

Comment: `<img src="http://example.com/image.php?1" /><img src="http://example.com/image.php?2" /><img src="http://example.com/image.php?3" />`

Comment: This might work... I was hoping to use the same URL for everything, because this will be placed in a forum signature.

Comment: To the browser, the same URL means the same image. Which is why you need to make the URL different each time.

Comment: Gah! None of these options seem to work! They still display the same image, even if I manually add a random GET parameter.

Comment: @Ignacio: Maybe a `&x=<?= microtime(true); ?>` would be less prone to caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the GET parameter 'img'.

[/path/to/images/rotate.php?img=my_static_image.jpg](http:///path/to/images/rotate.php?img=my_static_image.jpg)

More about the default GET parameter can you find in there documentation : http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/

Comment: It's a default option as you can see in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the URL the same then just add a no-cache header to your php script like so:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Hopefully any half decent browser will respect this and won't cache the first request.

Your other option is to modify your `rotate.php` script so that the code is contained within a function. Then you would use `include('rotate.php');` at the top of your script and use your new `rotate()` function wherever you need it.